# How do I make a stylized cartoon shader for my bark and leaf models in cycles engine?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, shaders

I added my own texture, and it looks horrible trying to create a realistic branch is "WAY" too much memory, so I'm going for a low budget look inspired by legend of Zelda breath of the wild. However, I don't know how to make those bold highlighted colors that blend in with each other in a cartoon way. I'm doing all this in Blender 3.6 on the cycles engine, and I can't seem to find any tutorials related to it if there's a simple solution that doesn't involve alpha transparency that be great, I've learned my lesson and it cost me a lot for my computer. I just need to know how to make an anime cartoon shader for low poly meshes while giving off the illusion of detail?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can we ask why alpha masking is not acceptable?

Comment: I was told according to Blender Guru in one of his videos that it adds a lot to render time that and also alpha masking has too much memory unless I'm wrong. I was just trying to be efficient without putting stress on my computer.

Comment: OK, he might be right.. I _guess?_ though, it's shovelling work from your CPU to your GPU, so it depends on your setup?

Comment: What do you mean by setup?

Comment: GPU/CPU . Still guessing, but if you're rendering on your GPU, and it's reasonably pokey, then maybe it will handle the alpha.

Comment: Oh well in that case yes, on "Device" it says GPU Compute is there anything else I need to do if not can you tell me how to make an artistic anime shader from Breath of the wild?

Comment: Would it be fair for you to edit a grab like [this](https://imgur.com/a/x0IvsGO) into your post?  Folks might know better what to aim for.

Comment: the images are not included in the file. You need to pack them (File > External Data > Pack Resources...) or post here a small demo version of it for the leaf. -- and is there a reason why you want to use Cycles? Both render engines will work but most toon shaders use Eevee.

Comment: Actually, that's another thing I notice everyone seems to use Eevee I only chose Cycles because it looked cool, I have no problem using Eevee is there a reason it's being used a lot for toon shading?